# How to separate the url and take one particular word

Tags: php

i would like to know how to separate the url and take only the particular brand name from the url

```
http://www.example.com/mobiles/nokia-mobile-price-list.php
http://www.example.com/camera/canon-camera-price-list.php
```

I want to separate this url and take only the brand names such as

> nokia ,  canon

```
$brand = "nokia";
$brand ="canon";
```

Comment: I tried something with explode function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
$url = parse_url("http://www.example.com/mobiles/nokia-mobile-price-list.php");
$brand = strstr(basename($url['path']) ,"-",true);

echo $brand ;
```

Output

```
 nokia
```

Comment: i am facing a small problem i.e in my DB table for sony ericsson it is like Sony Ericsson , where us the url is like http://www.example.com/mobiles/sonyericsson-mobile-price-list.php how to take and find the id of the brand name

Comment: It the same way ..... as the code above .. just remove the url and put this there ... see http://codepad.viper-7.com/jTHyyt

Comment: @Ragavendran Ramesh That's another question. Anyway, you can make a translation table using [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression, which will capture the part between `/` and `.php`, which does not contain `/` symbol.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/camera/canon-camera-price-list.php';
preg_match('/\/([^\/-]+)-[^\/]*.php/', $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```